# CiviOffice crashes when you access its Settings menu entry

Tags: civioffice

I just installed CiviOffice extension 1.0.0 on CiviCRM 5.71.1 under Wordpress 6.4.3. I am able to upload .docx files but when I access the CiviOffice > CiviOffice Settings entry of the menu, I get as error:

```
There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.
```

And no email seems to be sent with instructions.

I wonder how I can debug this error.

Comment: Check the web server log (e.g. apache or nginx)

Comment: No errors. By the way, the error message is not produced by the apache client but by the CMS Wordpress itself.

Comment: This error message should always produce an error message in your PHP logs.  Demerit was saying "web server log" but that's only applicable if you're using mod_php.  You can also enable the [WordPress debug log](https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/debug/debug-wordpress/) which won't cut off the backtrace.

Right now, this question is a generic WordPress debugging question, but once you have an error and backtrace, you should edit your question with them so that the original question can be answered.